# Legal Function Parameters

Tags: c++, function

While working with C++, I began wondering how code like `sizeof(int)` worked. I realize that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, but it still got me wondering... is code like `myFunc(double)` legal? Can you pass just the pure type of something, like `int` or `MyClass` to a function? Admittedly, I can't see much applications for that, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: No. If you want behaviour similar to `sizeof`, you could use type traits and template metaprogramming. If you want a syntax similar to `sizeof`, you could define a preprocessor macro that does something with the type name.

Comment: That's what templates are for, although only at compile time.

Comment: `template <typename T> void myFunc()`, `myFunc<double>()` is similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators like `sizeof` work because the language says that they do.

Not everything is a construct like a function that you can overload or recreate yourself. You can't make your own operator that takes a type name, just like you can't make your own primitive type, or declaration syntax.

You could not re-write `sizeof` in your C++ program and use it there (though its underlying implementation within the compiler is often written in C++! that's at another layer of abstraction, though).

There's no magic here; just facts of life.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Arguments are [expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5k6t6kf.aspx), and in C++ types are not expressions.

Templates are used for "type arguments", but they're only at compile-time. (See @Banex and @clcto, above.)